# Ползунок для настроек для PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

у меня есть игра в которой мне нужно сделать ползунок/полосу для настройки громкости музыки. Как это можно реализовать? Вот функция, которая запускает меню

```
def menu_setup():
    global gameplay, player_y, player_x, bg_x, fan_x, fan_y, in_jump
    if not gameplay:
        screen.blit(menu_bg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(start_lbl, (250, 300))
        screen.blit(setting_ico, (500, 30))
        if start_lbl_hb.collidepoint(mouse) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            player_x, player_y = 150, 295
            bg_x = 0
            fan_x, fan_y = 0, 0
            in_jump = False
            gameplay = True
            screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
            return gameplay
        if setting_ico_hb.collidepoint(mouse) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            screen.blit(menu_bg, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(setting_music, (300, 208))
            # тут мне нужен "ползунок"
    # func start when collide
    if player_hb.colliderect(fan_hb):
        gameplay = False
        screen.blit(menu_bg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(start_lbl, (250, 300))

    return gameplay
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? В реализации самого ползунка? В доступе к настройкам громкости?

Comment: Если вас интересует, как сделать сам ползунок — пожалуйста объясню. Берете, создаете класс, рисующий два прямоугольника, один длинный, другой короткий. В реализации событий мыши добавьте проверку на совпадение с координатами маленького квадрата. Дальше все вроде и так ясно.

Comment: Еще можете [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032822/how-to-insert-a-slider-in-pygame) почитать.

Comment: @Глеб , большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Я тут как-то написал библиотеку [pyne](https://github.com/nchistov/pyne) там есть немного виджетов, в том числе и ползунок. Но для встраивания виджетов в игру pygame, посмотрите класс `GameGUIController`. (Простите за рекламу )

Comment: @чистов_n, да, интересная библиотека, ознакомлюсь с ней на досуге.